# If $p<q$, then $\ell^p\subset\ell^q$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Is $\ell^p$ a subset of $\ell^q$ if $p<q$?

Can I use $a_n^q=a_n^pa_n^r$ with $q=p+r$?

Comment: No. Look for counterexamples. An easy one is $p=1,q=2$ and $a_n=\frac1n$. But you can build up a family of such counterexamples quite easily

Comment: The result holds. To see why, consider $(a_n)$ in $\ell^p$. Then $|a_n|\geqslant1$ for at most finitely many $n$s and, if $|a_n|\leqslant1$ then $|a_n|^q\leqslant|a_n|^p$. Thus, indeed, $(a_n)$ is in $\ell^q$, qed.

Comment: @b00nheT not sure what you mean there.

Comment: thanks Did, b00, 1/n is not in $l^1$.

Comment: @quid I am terribly sorry. I basically showed that that the converse inclusion is always wrong. Of course Did answer is the correct one.